# How to programmatically connect/re-connect pull-up resistors?

Tags: stm32, i2c, pullup, encoder

I’m using a [MT6701](http://www.magntek.com.cn/upload/MT6701_Rev.1.0.pdf) magnetic absolute encoder that supports both I2C readout and quadrature pulses (ABZ).
Inconveniently, the pins for the quadrature outputs A and B are the same pins for I2C’s SCL and SDA. I do want to use I2C to get the absolute value once in a while, but due to its limited baud rate I can’t read it with the desired frequency, so I need to also use the quadrature outputs.
Now the issue is that in order to use I2C I need to connect these pins to pull-up resistors, but then I don’t think the quadrature outputs would work properly. Therefore, I’m looking for a way to “de-couple” these pins from the pull-up resistors when I need to switch to using quadrature outputs, but I’m not sure how. Any ideas?

Comment: Why wouldn't it work with the pull-up resistors always in there? Quad encoder pulses tend to be dirt slow compared to something like I2C. Are you expecting your pulse rate to exceed 100,000 pulses per second? Remember, that's pulses on a SINGLE line. Not the encoder transitions across all lines.

Answer (score 6):

Typically there's no problem with connecting a pullup resistor to a push-pull output (just some wasted current when the output is low). Looks like it can drive 2mA with less than 0.5V drop so the typical 4.7K to 10K pullups should be fine.

But if you really need to do it, just use a couple small P-channel MOSFETs in series with the resistors..

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feTjgF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Great, thanks Spehro! Let me give this a try.

Answer (score 2):

You may be asking the wrong question. If you intend to use both the I2C mode and the ABZ mode you will most likely need to use a dual 1->2 demux component to isolate the I2C parts of your board from the ABZ part of the circuit. The same control signal used for the MODE select input to the chip can also be used as the select pin on the demux component.

Once this is in place the pull-up resistors for the I2C is simple. Just put them on the output of the demux on the side dedicated to the I2C part of the circuit.